# Send message TTL in header using spring cloud stream rabbit mq binder

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream

I want to use spring cloud stream rabbitMQ binder for message driven architecture.
But each message should have own time to live setting. so I need to give this setting in message header. Do you think is this possible using Spring Cloud Stream RabbitMQ Binder ?

```
   Message message1 = MessageBuilder.withPayload(new PFSimulationEvent(1, "sd"))
            .setHeader("to_process", true).setHeader("expiration", 10000)
            .build();
        output.send("simulatePf-out-0", message1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it in several ways - https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-function/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-function.html#_inputoutput_enrichment
The latest addition is via `input/output-header-mapping-expression`.

This feature is binder agnostic as it lives at the level of spring-cloud-function and will work with any binder.

Comment: What is difference if I modify header in the mean time of  message creation.  Please check updated thread.   I found "expiration" property from rabbitmq . Do you know this could be correct header type? 

Per-Message TTL in Publishers
A TTL can be specified on a per-message basis, by setting the expiration property when publishing a message.